# Can't deserialize json

Tags: c#, json

Can someone help me figure out how to deserialize this using json.net in C#? I have already successfully parsed a different json but its format was different. I've tried to use object and it says it needs to be an array and then I change it to array it says it needs to be an array..
Oh and there can be additional arrays with different "TYPE"..

```
"[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "TYPE": 1,
    "APP_TAG": 1,
    "alert": "[13:13] This is a Test Message - 0.",
    "sound": "Default",
    "badge": 0
  }
]"
```

Comment: use `dynamic` instead of `object`.

Comment: If this is a c# string you have to start it with `@"` for multi-line string and use double quotes in the string `""`

Comment: I just used this as an example, I'm actually getting the JSon array from a webcall..

Comment: Whenever you have the JSON I recommend your first stop is http://json2csharp.com. Plug in the JSON and it will give you the C# class(es) you need to deserialize into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is an array/list

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int TYPE { get; set; }
    public int APP_TAG { get; set; }
    public string alert { get; set; }
    public string sound { get; set; }
    public int badge { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(json);
```

Comment: How do I then get each object?

Comment: @user3322270 `items[i].ID` , items is a list. just loop over it.

Answer (score 1):

```
string json = @"[
  {
    'ID': 1,
    'TYPE': 1,
    'APP_TAG': 1,
    'alert': '[13:13] This is a Test Message - 0.',
    'sound': 'Default',
    'badge': 0
  }
]";

var items = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```